How to mark multiple tags in image-dired?
How do you mark multiple tags in image-dired?
1.jpg;foo;xyz;bar
2.jpg;foo;xyz;bar
3.jpg;foo;xyz;baz

I want 1 and 2 marked by foo and bar
